# Best way to trigger a Page activation workflow

Tags: aem

I have a requirement where I have around 800 pages under a path in **/content** hierarchy. Now, the content in some of those pages will get updated on a nightly basis though some automated process. I have a requirement to trigger a page activation workflow for all the pages that are updated. This has to happen instantaneously after the page content got updated. I actually thought of writing a custom code to manually call the page activation workflow once a page is updated. But, on reading some documentation, I thought a workflow launcher might be more suitable in this scenario.

However, I have some queries related to workflow Launcher:

1. Does it activate all the pages under the path that I mention in the path property while setting up the launcher or will it activate only those pages which are modified?
2. I we are logged in as admin, do we get a notification in the inbox for approval of this workflow?

Also, I wanted to know whether using the workflow launcher in this scenario is the best solution for my requirement. I'm relatively new to Workflows, so please help

Answer (score 4):

I actually implemented this requirement with the help of a launcher. The below were the settings that I have done. Its activates only those pages which are modified under the mentioned path.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. You can define the workflow launcher to listen to a specific property. So if your nightly update updates a specific property, the easiest is to have a launcher that checks for modification of this property:
   http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/workflows/wf-using.html#Starting Workflows When Nodes Change
2. Usually you should only log in as admin if you need to access system settings (/system/console) and not for daily work. I suggest you create an administrator user which is part of the group that would get the workflow notification. You can give this user full access to the CRX, but still I would really check if this is needed for daily tasks.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your answer. I would like to know one thing. Nightly feed updates the pages and will trigger the workflow launcher automatically. But, does this activate the pages automatically or, will a notification go to somebody to approve the workflow first before the pages get activated? How to achieve both these scenarios? I understand that we these are 2 different scenarios, and we will use only one of them (I think we will go with automatic page activation, without any approval needed) But still curious to know how do we achieve both these scenarios

Comment: The launcher only starts a workflow on specific events, but the actual flow can be defined within your workflow. Either you have an approval step in it or you directly activate the page. Have a look at the "Request for Activation" workflow that comes with CQ.

Comment: Assuming there is no approval step, will the pages get automatically get activated once the launcher starts the page activation workflow? Or do we need to perform any other steps to see the pages on Publish instance?

Comment: There has to be the workflow step that does the actual activation: "Activate Page/Asset", which can be found it in the sidekick below the category "WCM Workflow".

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your concrete requirements, if you want to activate the pages without starting a workflow first you can make use of the `com.day.cq.replication` package. If you obtain a reference to a [`Replicator`](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/index.html) object you can trigger replication of a node simply via a call to the `replicate` method.